# How to get multiple form field values in Google Analytics site search report?

Tags: google-analytics, php, search, site-search

I'm wondering how I can get multiple form field values into Google Site Search. For instance, I have a search form that has a drop down for year, make and model.

Once submitted I would like those three values to be submitted as one string to Google Site Search. My URL after submitting looks like `mysite.com/index.php?s=1&year=2007&make=Toyota&model=Tundra`

I have already created a query parameter in my Site Search Settings in Google Analytics called `search`. I just need help programmatically doing the rest.

Comment: I just started looking into having my own search form (style wise) last night and found that it is a lot of reading and testing. I will hit it again soon. I wish I had an answer. But I am glad you asked this question. I am interested in it too. I could benefit from the answer since your model is a good idea for some of what I do. One up-vote. Hopefully someone will have a solid answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can push data to analytics on search results site loading that way:

```
analytics.js: ga('send', 'pageview', '/search_results.php?search='+make+' - '+model+' - '+year);
```

But you need to get GET params from URL. Example:

```
function get(key_str) {
if(window.location.search) {
    var query = window.location.search.substr(1);
    var pairs = query.split("&");
    for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
        if(unescape(pair[0]) == key_str)
            return unescape(pair[1]);
    }
}}
```

Comment: so i'll have my regular ga pageview event, then another one?

Comment: Yes, it's harming a stats, but the best way in your case